# Color variations when playing video files through media players

Tags: windows-8, video, colors, mp4, wmv

I am a Software Engineer and using a HP ProBook 4540s laptop. I have installed windows 8.1 (64-bit) for myself and all the drivers are up-to-date.

When I play video files (I checked *.mp4 and *.wmv formats) I experience a fade in colors (actually it is like washed colors with extra brightness) which make it really hard to read fonts on the video. If I go to the source (which I have downloaded the video file) and play it online (YouTube or any player integrated with website), there would be issues in color.

It is not an issue with my laptop too. Because when I frag the same video on to the secondary monitor (which is Samsung S22C300 – 22 inches) it also shows faded colors.

Please note that, if I drag and drop the same video file (stored in  my computer) to the browser, that plays fine.

I tried different players such as KMPlayer, Media player classic, Windows media player, etc. They all have been infected. I re- installed codec packs either, still no luck.

I have attached two screen shots to see the difference clearly. Please advise me.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

could be that you need to adjust your color management settings.
Search for Color Management in windows search and this should bring op the color management window. Select your laptop display and make sure "use my setting for this device" is checked. Click add and choose "sRGB IEC61966-2.1" then set as default. If this is the current setting then just uncheck use my setting.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion, I followed your instructions very carefully. I'm sorry, it did not work for me. I am planning to re-install windows.